# Transfer an Ubuntu Server 32bit that runs on a Raspberry Pi, to a normal 64bit server

Tags: server, services, raspberrypi, migration

I have an Ubuntu Server (32-bit) running on a Raspberry Pi. Is it possible to transfer this OS to a normal 64-bit server so that I do not have to install all the running services from the beginning? How?

Comment: No, not a chance.

Comment: and I would advice to create a post install script that adds all the extra functionality you need so you do not need to do this manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. They are entirely different CPU architectures.  Raspberry Pi uses the ARM architecture. The software on a Raspberry Pi is not compatible with the x86-64 architecture on "normal" 64-bit hardware.

You will need to reinstall.